# Can i turn off /GL only for single cpp?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Can turn off optimization (/GL) for only one of the project files?

```
extern "C"
{
#pragma function(memset)
    void *memset(void *dest, int c, size_t count)
    {
        char *bytes = (char *)dest;
        while (count--)
        {
            *bytes++ = (char)c;
        }
        return dest;
    }
}
```

In this moment I have to turn off optimization for ALL project to compile it.

Comment: Why are you implementing `memset`?

Comment: I use clean winapi, so I turn off ctr completely, the compiler produces an error(not found symbol _memset) if not to do this. You have any ideas how do it without implementing  memset? @Lightness Races in Orbi

Comment: Sorry, what is "ctr"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean CRT.

Comment: I don't understand why you disable the C runtime and why this leads to "clean winapi", whatever that means

Answer (score 2):

Of course, this is compiler dependent. In Visual C++, insert the following into the cpp file above the function.

```
#pragma optimize( "", off )
```

To turn off global optimization only use this:

```
#pragma optimize("g", off)
```